# UINavigationController Adding Rows Implementation

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I was wondering if with a UINavigationController, can you have a "+" sign, like the Contacts app, that adds a row to the main root view and has a default name as "Setup", then you can click on that row to go to one level below, change a value in a UIPickerview in the one level below UIViewController, and then press the back button and have that value from the UIPickerView be the name of the new row that was created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (though it's not very Apple-like UI behavior!)

You'd have to put some special logic in your table view data source to add the "Setup" row and go to the picker when that row was selected. The root view controller should implement the delegate from the picker to receive the new row's name, then call `[self.tableView reloadData]` to update the view.

A better practice would be to model the Contacts app and let the "+" button present a modal view controller from the bottom for your picker view. Look at the `addButton` implementation in SQLiteBooks or CoreDataBooks.